# What does the Facebook Login plugin return?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

Does the Facebook login plugin return a signed request or an access code?

Comment: @jimmy, I think you should take a moment to read John Skeet's blog post about writing a good question. Simply adding the link to your main question would have improved your question tenfold. There are many code libraries associated with Facebook. You're leaving it to other users to guess which code you're referring to. I'm obviously not alone in my opinion. Rather than moaning about the attitude of those who are willing to help, it might be better to adjust your expectations. Anyway, take a look here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: "This facebook.SO business will get out of control. It will get out of control and we'll be lucky to live through it."  While we *do* have a special agreement with the *f* you still have to meet our quality standards when asking a question.  And other users have an obligation not to be rude when pointing this out.  The reason why StackOverflow is the best programming Q&A site on the internets is because we do our best (mods and the community) to keep the help vampires at bay.  It doesn't hurt anyone to read that Skeet article.  In fact, I might skim it again myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a successful authentication/authorization, the plugin returns an access code, what is officially termed as **Authorization Code**. Suggest that you read through [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks saket, luckily I have already built that for another project, I was sure if the login plugin was going to return a signed request like the registration plugin